# AWS Step Functions substring?

Tags: aws-step-functions

Is there a way using Intrinsic Functions and/or JSONPath to select a character location specific substring of a value? I have a field "ReportingPeriod" with the value "YYYYMM" (e.g. 202206) and I want to get values year: 2022, month: 06. If the value was 2022-06, I could use String.Split function, but with nothing to split the string on, I have to rely on character location. Any ideas?